# Expanding the precision or range of a random number generator

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

Suppose I have a random number generator that can produce a uniform distribution of natural numbers in the range $[1, 10]$. So there are 10 possible values the generator can produce.

Suppose I would like to generate natural numbers with a uniform distribution spanning $[1, 30]$. Is there a way to do that with my existing generator?

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029880/generating-a-number-using-a-coin/2029949

Comment: Beware that adding three of these random numbers (-2) will not yield a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, shift the ranges to `[0,9]` and `[0,29]`.

Draw a first number `A`. Draw a second one, `B`; if `9`, draw again until not `9`.

Compute `3.A + B/3`.

---

The reason to reject `9` is to ensure that `B/3` is uniform with probabilities `1/3`.

---

If I am right, you can also keep the remainder from one drawing to the next, add it to `B` (giving a uniform number in `[0,11]`) and divide by `4` instead of `3`.

```
Initialize R
Loop
    Draw A
    Draw B
    Output 3.A + (B+R) / 4
    Keep R = (B+R) % 4
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks Yves Daoust. I'm processing it - will let you know if I have any follow-on questions.